# Variables Inside Javascript OnClick event

Tags: javascript, html, vb.net

I have a program that ultimately sends a well formatted HTML based email via Exchange Web Services direct to customers.

I am attempting to add a link to another web page, via a Javascript OnClick Popup window.

This is the HTML I am using:

```
<a href="javascript&#58;;"
  onClick="window.open (
        'http://www.mydomain.co.uk/dlc/dlc_submission.php?branch=2&policyref="
         & GlobalVariables.strPolRef & "&brand=Test',
        'Submit DLC',
        'scrollbars=no,width=720,height=320'
      );
 ">Submit Code</a>
```

This URL would be made up of a variable "GlobalVariables.PolRef" which is the customer reference as it sends to a page that has hidden text boxes that then pass information to a Web Service.

Within the application the HTML Body is contained within a variable _HTML.

I usually replace all my HTML "s with a single quote ' because it doesn't play havoc with putting the entire HTML body string into a variable.

However in this instance if I change javascript surrounding `href` - it totally ruins the code.

Has anyone got an alternative solution to this for me please? Or can you point me in the right direction.

Comment: Imagine the havoc that could be played if mail clients executed javascript in emails...

Comment: Hi @JamesThorpe I'm guessing I may as well can this idea then and just do a basic URL link yeah?

Comment: I would, yes!  Personally, even if mail clients did run javascript, there's no way I'd ever click on a link in an email that didn't reveal the target url in full when I hover over it.

Comment: This is a security NO-NO